# Bash print line until second ' found

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have lines in file:

```
grep -B5 'xxx xx x x xx' filename | wc-l
grep 'yy zz aa' filename | wc -l
```

I need to get grep statement without filename and following command:

```
grep -B3 'xxx xx x x xx'
grep 'yy zz aa'
```

How can I do it by single command?

Comment: You want to find lines between two patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po ".*?'.*?'" file
```

Output:

```
grep -B5 'xxx xx x x xx'
grep 'yy zz aa'
```

Comment: This will do the work, I`ve made small change to limit it: grep -o ".*'[A-Za-z0-9]*'" it will not catch next grep in line. Thanks